# What to do with poor answers to opinion-based questions when reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review

[IRC channel for computer network related queries](https://superuser.com/questions/621642/irc-channel-for-computer-network-related-queries) seems to be opinion-based and should be closed. When someone answers the question like this one and I stumble on such answer when reviewing low-quality posts, should I recommend deletion or leave it alone?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the [initial revision of this post](https://superuser.com/posts/621675/revisions), it should have been recommended for deletion. It does not even contain a full sentence.

Of course, the bad answers are just symptoms of (possible) bad questions that need to be closed, but this does not make the answers any better. Just mark them for deletion.